# Googlebot couldn't get all resources for this page

Tags: google, google-search-console, css, googlebot

When I fetch and render it is showing partial. It looks fine. The same way Google sees it is the same way visitors see it.

The reason for this is that I've added BuySellaAd codes in a widget onto my sidebar and footer. When I remove it it's perfectly fine. I'm not blocking anything in my *robots.txt*. Is it normal that Google can't access external scripts? Please I don't want to get penalized or I don't want my rank to drop? What do I do? Do I leave the BuySellaAd codes?

Comment: It doesn't matter. That widget isn't important. Just ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You did not worry about it. Let me tell you more into this.

Google don't like ads that pass PageRank, and hence they suggest to add [nofollow tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en) in banners, but we can't use nofollow tag, in javascript. because `rel="nofollow"` tag working only in links.

**Update: Google support nofollow attribute in JavaScript link as well.**

Matt also suggest, use robots.txt to don't pass PageRank, it's also OK, when you can't use nofollow tag in banners. And Same thing apply here, Buysellads block those javascript in their robots.txt, and hence No Pagerank will pass, when publisher put ads on their site. And that's why you are getting blocked resource message in your dashboard. So don't worry **Google don't penalize neither publisher nor advertiser, because PageRank is not passed.**

Answer (score 0):

> Is it normal that Google can't access external scripts? Please I don't want to get penalized or I don't want my rank to drop? What do I do? Do I leave the BuySellaAd codes?

If the only resources google has a problem accessing are any resources required for third-party advertising (such as Buy-Sell Ads) then you don't have to worry and just leave the advertisements on. I use adsense on my site and googlebot reacts the same way towards it.

One reason you may have the issue with google is because the advertisement server has either blocked google from accessing the required advertisement resources via IP address blocking or through robots.txt. Legit search engines respect robots.txt.

Answer (score -1):

It is correct that Google (or any other searchengine spider) don't execute javascript when indexing your website. Google want to index data and javascript is code, not data. So script resources are ignored.

However more and more website deploy ajax techniques that 'inject' data into the website after the initial source is loaded. That leaves the possibility that the spider can't access all data, hence the warning you receiving.

However Google, Bing and other major search engines do have some powerful fraud detection programs that can detect that you're showing white text on a (almost) white background or jquery calls that remove elements with 'spam' data from the DOM, so you the visitor doesn't see that content or similar techniques..

FYI: Google developed the V8 javascript engine for Chrome and Microsoft developed the Chakra javascript engine for Edge..

Comment: Google absolutely will run JavaScript and has been for years. Part of the point of the Fetch and Render which did not have the render was to give an idea of how Googles new render engine would see the site. It was a bit rocky for a while, however recently, it has significantly improved. Not all JavaScript is run however. Most common reason for a blocked resource is that it exists or accesses 3rd part components. John is right. If you look to the panel on the right, generally you will see everything even sometimes what is said to be blocked. Ignore the notice. It is not an error but a notice.

Comment: Google does run javascript. Moste websites these days heavily rely on javascript to render content. Script resources are not ignored at all.